# how to play muted live stream in AVQueuePlayer ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, live-streaming, avqueueplayer

If live stream has no audio then AVQueuePlayer not streaming/playing it.
Is there a way to play the live stream if there is no sound.
I am using AVPlayerLayer and AVQueuePlayer..

AVQueuePlayer should play muted live stream.